# How do I rearrange my JButtons to to be in two rows at the top

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

My JButtons are in an asymmetrical row. I want them to be in 2 symmetrical rows at the top because I think that would look better. How would I do this?

Here is my code:

```java
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Fantasyrpglifesim {
    private  static int count = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel westPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel eastPanel = new JPanel();

        JButton age = new JButton("Age up");
        mainPanel.add(age);
        JButton character = new JButton("Character");
        mainPanel.add(character);
        JButton worldmap = new JButton("World map");
        mainPanel.add(worldmap);
        JButton setings = new JButton("Settings");
        mainPanel.add(setings);
        JButton jobs = new JButton("Jobs");
        westPanel.add(jobs);
        JButton manegement = new JButton("Management");
        westPanel.add(manegement);
        JButton family = new JButton("Relationships");
        westPanel.add(family);
        JButton cfafting = new JButton("Crafting");
        westPanel.add(cfafting);
        JButton newgame = new JButton("New game");
        eastPanel.add(newgame);
        JButton titorial = new JButton("tutorial");
        eastPanel.add(titorial);
        JButton log = new JButton("Log");
        eastPanel.add(log);
        JButton acheiments = new JButton("Achievements");
        eastPanel.add(acheiments);
        for (int x=0; x<14;x++){


        }
        westPanel.setVisible(true);
        eastPanel.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH,mainPanel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST,westPanel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST,eastPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1285, 678);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I have tried rearranging the JPanels, but that did not work. I just want them to be in two rows.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud use GridLayout to arrange the components in a rectangular grid.

Following example has GridLayout with two rows in one column.
It simply lays out buttons in a row since FlowLayout is the default layout manager for JPanel.

```
    JPanel row1Panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel row2Panel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    mainPanel.add(row1Panel);
    mainPanel.add(row2Panel);

    JButton age = new JButton("Age up");
    row1Panel.add(age);
    JButton character = new JButton("Character");
    row1Panel.add(character);

    JButton jobs = new JButton("Jobs");
    row2Panel.add(jobs);
    JButton manegement = new JButton("Management");
    row2Panel.add(manegement);
```

Comment: Why use two panels? A GridLayout can be configured for multiple rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

I rearranged your code and created the following GUI.

[image: buttons]

I used a `GridLayout` to create the `JButton` `JPanel`.

I separated the creation of the `JFrame` from the creation of the `JPanel`.  This makes the code easier to read and understand and allows me to focus on one part of the GUI at a time.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Fantasyrpglifesim implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Fantasyrpglifesim());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 6, 5, 5));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JButton age = new JButton("Age up");
        panel.add(age);
        JButton character = new JButton("Character");
        panel.add(character);
        JButton worldmap = new JButton("World map");
        panel.add(worldmap);
        JButton setings = new JButton("Settings");
        panel.add(setings);
        JButton jobs = new JButton("Jobs");
        panel.add(jobs);
        JButton manegement = new JButton("Management");
        panel.add(manegement);
        JButton family = new JButton("Relationships");
        panel.add(family);
        JButton cfafting = new JButton("Crafting");
        panel.add(cfafting);
        JButton newgame = new JButton("New game");
        panel.add(newgame);
        JButton titorial = new JButton("tutorial");
        panel.add(titorial);
        JButton log = new JButton("Log");
        panel.add(log);
        JButton acheiments = new JButton("Achievements");
        panel.add(acheiments);

        return panel;
    }

}
```